# Why do absolute redirect and relative redirect is behaving differently for prefix pathmatch in angular routes

Tags: angular8, angular-routing

I was trying to understand the difference between full and prefix path match in angular routes. So I used below codes just for the experiment

```
[
 { path: "", **redirectTo: "dashboard"**, pathMatch: "prefix" },
 { path: "dashboard", component: DashboardComponent },
 { path: "aboutus", component: AboutusComponent },
 { path: "**", component: PagenotfoundComponent }
]
```

But in this case, it is routing me to page not found component and the URL is coming as localhost:4200/dashboard/about us when I click on 'about Us' link present in the template.
But when I write the above code as below

```
[
 { path: "", **redirectTo: "/dashboard"**, pathMatch: "prefix" },
 { path: "dashboard", component: DashboardComponent },
 { path: "aboutus", component: AboutusComponent },
 { path: "**", component: PagenotfoundComponent }
]
```

then every other link routes to the dashboard link only which is understandable as an empty string "" is the prefix of every URL.
Can somebody please make me understand why it is behaving that way when we use relative redirect and how relative and absolute works here?